# Smooth Density Plot Using 'adjust'

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the classic diamonds dataset, `adjust` can be used to smooth the plot. Why does this not work with my dataset? `adjust` is ignored.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(year = c(1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 
                              1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1971
), age_group = structure(2:19, .Label = c("All ages", "0 to 4 years", 
                                          "5 to 9 years", "10 to 14 years", "15 to 19 years", "20 to 24 years", 
                                          "25 to 29 years", "30 to 34 years", "35 to 39 years", "40 to 44 years", 
                                          "45 to 49 years", "50 to 54 years", "55 to 59 years", "60 to 64 years", 
                                          "65 to 69 years", "70 to 74 years", "75 to 79 years", "80 to 84 years", 
                                          "85 to 89 years", "90 to 94 years", "95 to 99 years", "100 years and over", 
                                          "Median age"), class = "factor"), population = c(1836149, 2267794, 
                                                                                           2329323, 2164092, 1976914, 1643264, 1342744, 1286302, 1284154, 
                                                                                           1252545, 1065664, 964984, 785693, 626521, 462065, 328583, 206174, 
                                                                                           101117), age_min = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 
                                                                                                                55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85), age_max = c(4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 
                                                                                                                                                         34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59, 64, 69, 74, 79, 84, 89)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_density(adjust = 1)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_density(adjust = 5)

ggplot(pop_dn_filtered, aes(x = age_min, y = population)) + 
  geom_density(stat = "identity", adjust = 5)
# Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: adjust
```

Comment: Should we assume `pop_dn_filtered` is `df` above?

Comment: it doesn't work with `stat = "identity"`. The following ```ggplot(df, aes(population)) + 
  geom_density(adjust = 5)``` works with no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_density()` is most often used like a smooth histogram show the density of a vector across its values, e.g. to show how much more frequent `5` appears than `30`. Based on `adjust` or `bw`, the function bins your `x` values to the granularity you specify and outputs the density to `y`. The specific use here using `stat = "identity"` overrides that counting process and uses the `y` you have specified, i.e. population.

Your data is currently in summarized form, where each line represents the count of all the people in an age group, rather than each one being one person. We could undo that using `tidyr::uncount`, which copies each row the number of times you specify for that row. So if the population is 5 million for one row, we could copy it 5 million times. But that's almost certainly overkill for this; we might instead copy it a smaller number that's in proportion to 5 million:

```
df %>% uncount(population/1E4)
# Produces one row for every 10,000 population; in this case 2,183 rows, corresponding to the 
# 22M total population in the data
```

So we could use this construction to get control over smooth binning within `geom_density`:

```
ggplot(df %>% uncount(population/1E4), aes(x = age_min)) + 
  geom_density(adjust = 0.7)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df %>% uncount(population/1E4), aes(x = age_min)) + 
  geom_density(adjust = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful Mr. Snow. So once I omit, `stat = "identity"` I lose the population values on the y-axis. If I want the smoothness of this density graph with the population values on the y-axis, what are my options?

Comment: Your question was around why geom_density didn't work as expected, but it sounds like what you lly want to know now is "how do I make a smooth line through/near my points?" I'd suggest `geom_smooth(se=F)` or `ggforce::geom_bspline()`

Comment: Your answer made me realize that geom_density may not be the correct approach. Thanks.